# httprequest not autowired in aspect

Tags: spring, servlets, aspectj

I am intercepting calls to getDescription method of a certain class using following aspect.

```
@Aspect
public class InternationalizationAspect {

    private static final String LANGUAGE_CODE_ENGLISH = "en";
    private static Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(InternationalizationAspect.class);

    @Autowired
    InternationalizationService internationalizationService;

    @Autowired
    private HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest;

    @Around("execution(* com.***.***.***.***.getDescription(..))")
    public Object getInternationalizedTitleDescription(ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint) throws Throwable {
        log.info("title getdescription intercepted");
        if (httpServletRequest == null) {
            log.info("http servlet request was not autowired correctly");
            return joinPoint.proceed();
        } else {
            Locale locale = httpServletRequest.getLocale();
            log.info("locale is = " + locale);
            if (locale.getLanguage().equals(new Locale(LANGUAGE_CODE_ENGLISH).getLanguage())) {
                return joinPoint.proceed();
            } else {
                log.info("getting internationalized description");
                Title t = (Title) joinPoint.getTarget();
                return internationalizationService.getTitleDescriptionFromTitleAndLocale(t, locale);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

For the above aspect, I get following output:

```
title getdescription intercepted
http servlet request was not autowired correctly
title getdescription intercepted
http servlet request was not autowired correctly
title getdescription intercepted
http servlet request was not autowired correctly
title getdescription intercepted
http servlet request was not autowired correctly
```

In my applicationContext.xml, I have:

```
<bean id="internationalizationAspect" class="com.***.***.***.InternationalizationAspect" />
<context:component-scan base-package="com.***">
        <context:exclude-filter expression=".*_Roo_.*" type="regex"/>
        <context:exclude-filter expression="org.springframework.stereotype.Controller" type="annotation"/>
</context:component-scan>
```

Why is spring not autowiring httpservletrequest in my aspect. According to this answer: [Spring AOP and aspect thread safety for an autowired HTTPServletRequest bean](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10541934/spring-aop-and-aspect-thread-safety-for-an-autowired-httpservletrequest-bean)

it should work.

**EDIT**

My web.xml resembles following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee
                            http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd">

    <display-name>Spring Web Application example</display-name>

    <!-- Configurations for the root application context (parent context) -->
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>
            /META-INF/spring/applicationContext.xml
        </param-value>
    </context-param>

    <!-- Configurations for the DispatcherServlet application context (child context) -->
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>spring-mvc</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>
                /WEB-INF/spring/mvc/spring-mvc-servlet.xml
            </param-value>
        </init-param>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>spring-mvc</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/admin/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

I am defining my aspect bean in applicationcontext.xml which is not in spring-mvc-servlet.xml

Answer (score 0):

You need to enable annotation configuration, either with

```
<context:annotation-config />
```

or

```
<context:component-scan ... />
```

With the above and assuming you're operating on a bean, the `@Autowired` field can never be `null`. If Spring can't inject it, it will throw exceptions.

Comment: Thanks for all the answers @Sotirios! I have added the details. I have context: component-scan, but there are some exclude filter tags in it. I dont really understand them well.

Comment: @ris The exclude filters won't affect this situation. Are you saying it is still null? Do you have two context files? One for the dispatcher servlet and one for the contextLoaderListener?

Comment: It is still null. I already had component-scan in place. Yes I have two context files one for dispatcher servlet and other for contextLoaderListener

Comment: Hi Sotitios, sorry for delay, I have updated the post with web.xml

Comment: @riship89 Ok, let's just be complete. I don't want to guess lol. Post the full `applicationContext.xml` and the full servlet context configuration. Does your `@Aspect` also have any `@Component` annotation?

Comment: Sotirios, I need to strip those files down a lot before uploading. My aspect does not have any @Component annotation.

Comment: @riship89 Ok wait. It's not possible for an injection target, ie. an `@Autowired` field to be `null` if you have the elements in my answer above. Does your servlet context by any chance also declare a `<bean>` for the aspect? If so, does it have the `<component-scan>` or `<annotation-config>` elements?

Comment: my servlet context does not have a bean for that aspect, but it has <context:component-scan> element. My application context has bean for my aspect (as mentioned in the original question). my application context also has <component-scan>

Comment: @riship89 I seriously don't see how it could be `null`. Can you confirm that the injected `internationalizationService` is not `null`?

Comment: internationalizationService is null as well.

Comment: @riship89 Seems like your `component-scan` is messing with it. Refactor your packages and remove the `exclude-filter` elements.

Comment: Are you kidding me? Have a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19327318/929701. That worked.

Comment: @riship89 That's a workaround though. The injection should work too, not necessarily for aspects. If you have the patience, you should look into your `component-scan` situation. If you want to debug, `AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor` is what handles injecting beans into `@Autowired` fields.

Comment: yes, I will spend some time debugging my annotations. Thanks you so much for helping me out here.

Comment: Hi Sotirios, please see this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9658819/929701. This worked as well. Do you know what does factory method aspectOf do?

Comment: @riship89 That's a bunch of AspectJ configuration elements. Are you using AspectJ? That's very possibly involved. I'd have to see more of your context configuration.